# Posting Credentials To C# Login Page

Tags: c#, post, authentication, httpwebrequest, firebug

I wrote a test login page(.aspx) which has one Postback method and a second static Webmethod call. The javascript function takes the value from "txt1" and "txt2" and calls the C# [WebMethod]

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="txt1" />
<input type="text" id="txt2" />

//JS function sends values to C# WebMethod
PageMethods.ReceiveUsernamePassword(txt1.value, txt2.value);
```

C#:

```
    [WebMethod]
    public static string ReceiveUsernamePassword(string user, string pass)
    {
        File.AppendAllText(@"C:\Z\upjs.txt", user + " " + pass + " js " + "\r\n\r\n\r\n");
        return "Success JS";
    }
```

A separate Client app that simulates a POST using following code below. URL points to localhost:1073/PostData_Server/Default.aspx/ReceiveUsernamePassword:

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
            System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection reqparm = new System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection();
            reqparm.Add("user", "user1");
            reqparm.Add("pass", "password1");
            byte[] responsebytes = client.UploadValues("http://local:1073/PostData_Server/Default.aspx", "POST", reqparm);
            string responsebody = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responsebytes);
        }
```

[image: Firebug POST Data]

[image: Firebug response]

Instead of getting "Success" or "Success JS" on my test client app, I am receiving the entire HTML document as the response message. Also no text file is written on the server side. I verified that it was not an error in my client app by downloaing Poster(https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/poster/). It too receive the entire HTML document as the response. How can I correct this?

Comment: The clue is probably in the HTML response message. Post the response panel for a failed call.

Comment: @Malk The response message is my login page's HTML document word for word as seen in Visual Studio. Here is a snippet: Username:\r\n        <input name=\"txt_username\" type=\"text\" id=\"txt_username\" />\r\n   <br />\r\n   Password\r\n    <input name=\"txt_password\" type=\"text\" id=\"txt_password\" />\r\n        <br />\r\n        <input type=\"submit\" name=\"btn_submit\" value=\"Submit\" id=\"btn_submit\" />\r\n\r\n        <br />\r\n        <br />\r\n        <br />\r\n        <br />\r\n        <br />\r\n\r\n        Username:\r\n        <input id=\"txtusername\" type=\"text\" />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just thought I'd update my findings on this question. It turns out in order to call the [WebMethod], the ContentType must be set to "application/json". You also cannot use WebClient.UploadValues() because it wont let you change the ContentType. So in order to send the correct POST signature, you must use the HttpWebRequest Class.

Also note: username and password sent MUST be in json format!

```
    HttpWebRequest myHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(URL);
    myHttpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
    myHttpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json; encoding=utf-8";

    using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(myHttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
    {
        string json = "{user:\"user1\",pass:\"pass1\"}";

        streamWriter.Write(json);
        streamWriter.Flush();
    }

    var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse();
    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        responsebody = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    }
```